# Debugging ModelBuilder Error 999999?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, table, error-999999, xy

I have to build a model for my class midterm which requires us to take a .csv file and convert it to a table, then take the table and create an XY event layer which will be used to create a new feature class.  From that new feature class, I am to break the trees into separate feature classes by tree species which will be placed into a feature dataset.  When I run the model as built with the first .csv file for Lake Shore Trees, it runs as it should and I get exactly what I was expecting.  The problem I keep running into is when I go to run the model again and this time change the allowable parameters for the next .csv file to be run, I keep getting "Error 999999" and the only other additional information is "failed to execute Feature Class to Feature Class."  When I look in my catalog tab, I see that the model has added only one feature to the feature NorthPark dataset, when there should be a total of three features in the dataset.  Now if I build a completely new model and use NorthPark as my initial input .csv file for the model, it runs as expected and all features are added to the dataset, but I get the same error again when I go and change the input parameters for the LakeShore .csv file.  Anyone have an explanation as to why this might be happening?[image: Model][image: Error]

Comment: Since the error seems to be coming from FeatureClassToFeatureClass try reviewing these Q&As: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Berror-999999%5D+featureclasstofeatureclass

Comment: When looking at my model again, I notice that the two feature classes that it is not adding to my LakeShore dataset are "Oak" and "Maple."  I'm guessing that the way the model is setup that since those two feature classes exist already in my NorthPark dataset, it is not creating them in the LakeShore dataset.  Is there a way to get those two features to write to my LakeShore dataset?

Comment: Feature class names need to be unique within a geodatabase and cannot exist in another feature dataset within the same geodatabase.

Comment: Thanks!  Your last reply helped me see why I was getting my error.  I was able to go in and fix it and get the model to function as it should when the parameters are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [your comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258485/debugging-modelbuilder-error-999999?noredirect=1#comment408549_258485):

> When looking at my model again, I notice that the two feature classes
>   that it is not adding to my LakeShore dataset are "Oak" and "Maple."
>   I'm guessing that the way the model is setup that since those two
>   feature classes exist already in my NorthPark dataset, it is not
>   creating them in the LakeShore dataset.

it appears that you are trying to create two feature classes of the same name, albeit in different feature datasets, in the same geodatabase.

Feature class names need to be unique within a geodatabase and cannot exist in another feature dataset within the same geodatabase.